# apache error log expecting DH and EC parameters in certificate

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I have been trying for 7 hours to start my Apache web server after I obtained new SSL certificates from LetsEncrypt. I have obtained an ECDSA certificate and the server still failing to start with the logs:

```
[Thu Mar 29 19:23:43.839012 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19908:tid 140570990629824] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Thu Mar 29 19:23:43.839038 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19908:tid 140570990629824] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Thu Mar 29 19:23:43.839069 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19908:tid 140570990629824] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Thu Mar 29 19:23:43.839086 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19908:tid 140570990629824] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

The configurations of SSL in VirtualHosts is:

```
ServerName site.example.com
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/ecdsa/site.example.com/0001_chain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/ecdsa/site.example.com/privkey.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the game, perhaps, but I came past this page between searching for an answer to the same error messages and finding the solution. If you carried over your VirtualHost configuration from httpd-2.2, like I did, I'm sure there is nothing wrong with it. Nor is there likely a problem with your openssl. For the record: There isn't a dhparams.pem file anywhere on my system. This just work a little different for httpd-2.4 it seems. First the clue: You can't rely on just your VirtualHost definition anymore. You *must* reference a valid certificate/key pair from conf.d/ssl.conf like so (locations are for my Fedora system):

> SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
>
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.pem

Mine is a self-signed cert, carried over from httpd-2.2/openssl-1.0.2h. The cert is in ascii PEM format. The key was converted to an RSA clear copy, so no password is required when httpd starts. (carefully evaluate your environment before you do that). It doesn't matter much what the cert is made for it seems, because it is still the certs, defined in the VirtualHost section that will be presented to the clients. For me those certs (carried over from httpd-2.2) are in PEM short form, while the respective keys, again are in RSA clear copy form. Of course you must have mod_ssl.so loaded, but if you had things working in httpd-2.2 then you already did that.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [Thu Mar 29 19:23:43.839012 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19908:tid 140570990629824] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
> ```

This line tells you, that you may have played with DH Parameters, for instance located here:

```
/etc/ssl/dhparams.pem
```

The problem is, if you want to increase DH security and play with this file such as follows:

```
sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem.new 4096
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo mv /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem.new /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem
sudo service apache2 start
```

Note, that if you store the `dhparams.pem` in non-standard location, you will have to provide the path to that file in your Apache configuration, for example in:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf
```

As follows:

```
# Use my own generated DH Parameters file 4096 bits long
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/dhparams.pem"
```

---

> ```
> [Thu Mar 29 19:23:43.839038 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19908:tid 140570990629824] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
> ```

This line is telling us, you have maybe played with ECDHParameters.

IMHO, it is best to stick with automatic setting:

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd ECDHParameters Automatic
```

See `man ecparam` for more information. I personally haven't had compelling reason to play with this one.

---

> ```
> [Thu Mar 29 19:23:43.839069 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19908:tid 140570990629824] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
> ```

This line is telling you that your specified private key is missing or the whole setup is malconfigured.